# In D&D 5e is it possible to add a breastplate to leather armor for an AC bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, armor-class

I just started playing D&D, and I'd like to know if it is possible to add a breastplate to leather armor for an AC bonus?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### No.

Different from previous editions, armor does not give a + to AC. they **set the AC** to a particular value, **then** bonuses and penalties are applied.

Leather armor grants AC 11 (it is not a +1 to AC. It is straight 11).

Breastplate grants AC 14.

If you are a barbarian with 16 CON, you'd have AC 13 + Dex from the unarmored defense, and would not benefit from wearing leather armor.

One historical tidbit: Breastplate armor **was** worn over leather. It was not a hardened boiled leather cuirass like the leather armor, but a [buff coat](http://www.yorkstories.co.uk/details/images/fairfax_buff_coat/thomas_fairfax_buff-coat_castle_museum_180510_300400.jpg) jacket.

**TL;DR:** Layering armor is useless for AC purposes. You would only get the biggest AC and possibly a lot of penalties.

Comment: So aside from acquiring heavier armor or magical buffs there isn't a way to increase your AC.

Comment: To clarify: D&D 5e Breastplate armor already includes a leather undercoat, if you read the description.